# PHP remove the last character from my loop

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm writing a string from my form and I'd like to remove the last comma from the end.  I understand that I can use the rtrim(), but I don't understand how I can return a variable from my loop.  I'm sure this is an easy answer, just super confused.  Thanks!

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

foreach ( $_POST['data'] as $data )
{

    echo $data['Monday'];
    echo $data['Tuesday'];
    echo $data['Wednesday'];
    echo $data['Thursday'];
    echo $data['Friday'];
    echo $data['Saturday'];
    echo $data['Sunday'];
    echo ", ";
}

} // end if
```

Comment: Gather them in a string and cut of the last 2 characters of it before echoing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if you are on the last element and skip printing the comma if so:

```
end($_POST['data');             // fast forward to the end of the array
$lastKey = key($_POST['data');  // and remember what the last key is

foreach ( $_POST['data'] as $key => $data )
{
    echo $data['Monday'];
    echo $data['Tuesday'];
    echo $data['Wednesday'];
    echo $data['Thursday'];
    echo $data['Friday'];
    echo $data['Saturday'];
    echo $data['Sunday'];
    if ($key !== $lastKey) echo ", ";
}
```

This approach feels cleaner to me: prevention is better than treatment.

Comment: Although I logically agree with your idea `prevention is better than treatment` it still feels like having a condition you can avoid having in a loop is wrong to me. +rep though as I haven't thought of that, ever, lol..

Comment: @php_nub_qq: I agree that it would be even cleaner to not have the condition, but: a) it's not going to matter in practice -- you 'd have to make maybe billions of iterations to measure a difference and b) any attempt to remove the condition will incur its own (most likely higher) resource cost. Can you suggest something better?

Comment: not really, and I'm not saying it's something that you should concern as bad or consuming, it's just like a pet peeve :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of echo'ing the data immediately, store it in a buffer...

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $buffer = "";
  foreach ( $_POST['data'] as $data )
  {
      $buffer .= $data['Monday'];
      $buffer .= $data['Tuesday'];
      $buffer .= $data['Wednesday'];
      $buffer .= $data['Thursday'];
      $buffer .= $data['Friday'];
      $buffer .= $data['Saturday'];
      $buffer .=  $data['Sunday'];
      $buffer .= ", ";
  }
  $buffer = rtrim($buffer, ", ");
  echo $buffer;
} // end if
```

Or, even shorter:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  implode(", ", $data);
} // end if
```

Assuming `$data` only has those Monday-Sunday keys..

Comment: is it also possible to: $newdata = ($_POST['data'], ", "); foreach($newdata as $data) ?

Comment: @magicianIam I don't think that's valid. You could do `implode(", ", $_POST['data'])` - if that's what you meant.

Comment: that would be a solution though i still want to see what $_POST['data'] contains and why is there only one and the TS could have a shorter answer

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a variable

```
$str = null;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    foreach ( $_POST['data'] as $data )
    {

        $str .= $data['Monday'] .
        $data['Tuesday'] .
        $data['Wednesday'] .
        $data['Thursday'] .
        $data['Friday'] .
        $data['Saturday'] . 
        $data['Sunday'] . 
        ", ";

    }
$str = substr($str,0,-2);
}
```

Then you have the data in `$str` which you can then echo or do stuff with

Answer (score 1):

You could get the last index of the `$_POST['data']` and simply not echoing a `,` when that's reached:

```
end($_POST['data']);
$last_key = key($_POST['data']);
foreach ($_POST['data'] as $key => $data) {
    // echoes here
    if ($key != $last_key) {
        echo ',';
    }
}
```